How do you stop a value saved in Preferences Datastore from resetting when the app is relaunched?
Whenever I relaunch an app, values that are saved in Preferences Datastore are reset.
In particular, I'm trying to save whether the user selected light mode or dark mode for their preferred background theme. However it doesn't maintain when the app is relaunched.
I'm using a boolean to determine the background theme and then save it using Preferences Datastore.
Here is the datastore class that is used to access the value:
import android.content.Context
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.Preferences
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.booleanPreferencesKey
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.edit
import androidx.datastore.preferences.preferencesDataStore
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.map

private val Context.dataStore by preferencesDataStore("ThemeDatastore")

class ThemeDatastore(private val context: Context) {
    val themeKey = booleanPreferencesKey("Theme")

    fun loadTheme(key: Preferences.Key<Boolean>): Flow<Boolean> =
        context.dataStore.data.map { preferences ->
            preferences[key] ?: false
        }

    suspend fun saveTheme(key: Preferences.Key<Boolean>, data: Boolean) {
        context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[key] = data
        }
    }
}

The following is the Compose code in Main Activity.
This is the instance of ThemeDatastore. It has the current local context in the context parameter field:
val themeDatastore = ThemeDatastore(LocalContext.current)

Here is the variable that retrieves the preferred background theme. It is initially set to false:
val savedTheme = themeDatastore.loadTheme(key = themeDatastore.themeKey).collectAsState(initial = false)

Here is the boolean variable that determines the background theme. If false, light mode is active, if true, dark mode is active. It is initially set to false:
var isDarkModeActive by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

Here is the function that calls the function from ThemeDatastore that saves the preferred background theme:
fun saveTheme(){
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        themeDatastore.saveTheme(themeDatastore.themeKey, isDarkModeActive)
    }
}

Here is the app layout. Is is a box that takes up the entire screen. The background color animates to dark gray if isDarkModeActive and saveTheme.value are both equal to true:
Box(
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(
            color = animateColorAsState(
                targetValue = if (isDarkModeActive && savedTheme.value)
                    Color.DarkGray else Color.White
            ).value
        )
        .fillMaxSize(),
) {
    Button(onClick = {
        isDarkModeActive = !isDarkModeActive
        saveTheme()
    }) {
        Text(text = "Toggle Theme")
    }
}

In the center of the screen is a button. When the button is pressed, isDarkModeActive is toggled between true and false and the saveTheme function is triggered.
I tried setting the initial value of the savedTheme variable to true. It didn't work.

Just to make sure, this only happens when you relaunch the app in Android Studio? When you relaunch the app using the device itself everything is fine? If not then please [edit] the question and remove the explicit mention of Android Studio in that context.

Okay I removed mentions of Android Studio.

The DataStore works perfectly fine, it is just that you explicitly set your dark mode to false when your composable is loaded:
var isDarkModeActive by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

The value of the DataStore doesn't matter, isDarkModeActive will always be false when you restart the app.
You should only have a single source of truth for any given data. In this case that means that you should remove one of the two values that indicate if the dark mode is on:
val themeDatastore = ThemeDatastore(LocalContext.current)
val isDarkModeActive by themeDatastore.loadTheme(key = themeDatastore.themeKey)
    .collectAsStateWithLifecycle(false)
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

Box(
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(
            color = animateColorAsState(
                targetValue = if (isDarkModeActive)
                    Color.DarkGray else Color.White,
            ).value,
        )
        .fillMaxSize(),
) {
    Button(onClick = {
        scope.launch {
            themeDatastore.saveTheme(themeDatastore.themeKey, !isDarkModeActive)
        }
    }) {
        Text(text = "Toggle Theme")
    }
}

Although not necessary to fix this problem, I made two additional changes:

I replaced collectAsState with collectAsStateWithLifecycle from the gradle dependency androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose to save resources when the lifecycle changes.
I removed the function saveTheme which createad an unmanaged CoroutineScope. Instead, you should retrieve a managed scope with rememberCoroutineScope().

This should now work as intended.
One last thing: The key you pass to loadTheme and saveTheme should be private to ThemeDatastore and directly be used by the functions, not passed as a parameter. There will never be a situation where you would want to use something else than themeDatastore.themeKey.

It worked. Thank you kind sir. However there is one more issue. When the app launches, it will start on light mode and then immediately transition to dark mode. Can that be fixed?

That is determined by the initialValue passed to collectAsStateWithLifecycle. That value will be taken until the DataStore provides its first value. You can set it to true if you want (then it will always start in dark mode until the setting from the DataStore is available), you can even set it to null and, further down, decide what you want to do when the information dark (false) or light (true) isn't available. It's more about what you want.

If my answer helped to solve your problem you can upvote and accept it by clicking the check mark on the left. You can also go through your old questions and select a solution that helped you. That will also help future visitors of the site who stumble upon your question to determine the quality of the answers. In addition it provides some reputation points for you and the author of the answer you accept.
